# Can I put reference dll in specific directory in C#?

Tags: c#, dll, reference, 32bit-64bit

I am working on 32-bit computer but deploying to 64-bit server.

I have 5 projects in a solution as below:

- IHCommon (Class Library)

  - Reference

    - IHLib64 (as a project)
    - IHLib32 (as a project)
- IHLib64 (Class Library)

  - Reference

    - aLibrary.dll (3rd party dll compiled for 64-bit computers)
- IHLib32 (Class Library)

  - Reference

    - aLibrary.dll (3rd party dll compiled for 32-bit computers)
- IHWebUtility (Class Library)

  - Reference

    - IHCommon (as a project)
- WebSite (Web Project)

  - Reference

    - IHWebUtility (as a project)

Here is my point.
My WebSite application has to run some function written in "aLibrary.dll", so I managed to call "IHLib64" or "IHLib32" from "IHCommon" project in condition of CPU type.

It works fine.

The problem is in WebSite's bin folder, 32-bit version of "aLibrary.dll" is trying to locate as 64-bit version of "aLibrary.dll" wants to locate.

They have same name, so they cannot stay in a same folder.

How can I seperate them into seperate folders like bin\x86 and bin\x64?

My real big point is to have them in my solution, but run them in condition of CPU type.

I have tried to fix .csproj file, but it quite didn't work out.

[EDIT]
I also have tried to use .NET Reflection, but I really cannot apply that to my previous code.

The codes are too huge convert.

[EDIT] To Daniel

Do you mean, I have to fix these projects as below:

- IHCommon (Class Library)

  - DLL

    - x86

      - aLibrary.dll (3rd party dll compiled for 32-bit computers)
    - x64

      - aLibrary.dll (3rd party dll compiled for 64-bit computers)
- IHWebUtility (Class Library)

  - Reference

    - IHCommon (as a project)
- WebSite (Web Project)

  - Reference

    - IHWebUtility (as a project)

Comment: How about separate post build xcopy for each platform?

Comment: The problem is 4 projects starts with "IH" are common projects, so other people have to use them in another projects. Therefore, physical path can be different in every projects. Then, it might occur another problems to xcopy. Would you like to suggest another workaround for me? Thx for your quick reply~ Kip9000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one of my projects I had a similar problem:

I wanted to have *one* deployment package that could run on x86 and x64 machines without any changes. It also made use of third party DLLs compiled for one CPU type. I had managed and unmanaged third party DLLs.
The DLLs for x86 were in a sub folder called x86 and the ones for x64 were in a sub folder named x64.

The approach for the unmanaged DLLs was to pre-load them, before the code really needed them. With this approach I could decide which version to load:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string path);

void LoadLibraryIfExists(string path)
{
    if (File.Exists(path))
        LoadLibrary(path);
}

var assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() ?? Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.Location);
path = Path.Combine(path, Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86", "unmanaged.dll");

LoadLibraryIfExists(path);
```

Any code that executed later and needed the same unmanaged DLL used the version loaded by the code above.

For managed assemblies, you have to hook into the `AssemblyResolve` event and resolve the assembly yourself. Just like before, you now can decide which one to load.
The following code has been used:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += 
    (s, e) => OnAssemblyResolve(Environment.Is64BitProcess, e.Name);

private Assembly LoadAssemblyIfExists(string path)
{
    if (!File.Exists(path))
        return null;
    return Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
}

private Assembly OnAssemblyResolve(bool is64BitProcess, string assemblyDisplayName)
{
    try
    {
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(assemblyDisplayName);

        if (assemblyName.Name == "Managed")
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() ?? 
                           Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
            var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.Location);
            path = Path.Combine(path, is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86", "Managed.dll"); 

            return LoadAssemblyIfExists(path);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var message = string.Format(
            "Error resolving assembly {0}. Falling back to default resolve behavior", 
            assemblyDisplayName);
        Logger.WarnException(message, e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

It is important to execute this code at the very beginning of your application.

Comment: I have changed my solution structure, can u please check it?

Comment: by the way, which one(aLibrary.dll - 32bit or aLibrary.dll - 64bit) do I have to add as reference? thx Daniel for your quick response.

Comment: @JoshuaSon: Than add the 32 bit version as you are developing on a 32 bit system.